# ¿Por qué en el siguiente código no es necesario importar cuando uso Switch y sí lo es al usar If?

Tags: java, condiciones

El siguiente código funciona, sin embargo ¿Por qué puedo usar la constante DOWN (de KeyCode), dentro del Switch, si nunca importo KeyCode?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Question extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch(e.getCode()) {
                case DOWN:
                    System.out.println("Down presionado!"); break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        pane.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Y ¿Por qué cuando uso, en lugar de Switch, un If sí necesito importar KeyCode para usar la constante DOWN?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Question extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN)
                System.out.println("Down presionado!");
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        pane.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Trate intentar usar KeyCode.DOWN dentro del Switch y DOWN dentro del If, ambos dan error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisás KeyCode, vas a ver que es un Enum.

Al utilizar un switch, las constantes de enumeración son incluídas en el alcance de las etiquetas CASE de una instrucción SWITCH, como se menciona en esta sección (6.3) del Java Language Specification (especificamente en la linea 12)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3

> The scope of an enum constant C declared in an enum type T is the body
>   of T, and any case label of a switch statement whose expression is of
>   enum type T (§14.11).